# How do I launch a bash script using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, bash

Just like the title says, how do I launch a bash script in my ~/Downloads folder using a keyboard shortcut? I've tried binding `cd ~/Downloads && ./bash-script.sh` to different accelerators (ex. the "Tools" button or music player button on my keyboard, and F4) but no luck, yes the script is marked executable, I am trying to do this under "Custom Shortcuts" in System Settings -> Keyboard, and the command works in Terminal.

Comment: have you tried binding '/home/Downloads/bash-script.sh' ?   I'm assuming you have your #!/bin/bash as the first line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a keyboard shortcut to launch a script to start conky for me.

Now it sounds like you have tried to 'all the right things'. In the command section of keyboard shortcuts I have: `/home/karl/bin/start-conky.sh`

If you have `cd ~/Downloads && ./bash-script.sh` in that field have you tried changing it to: `/home/username/Downloads/bash-script.sh`?

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I'm a little new to making my own scripts. @Matt No, my script starts with "cd ~/Downloads". Should it start with #!/bin/bash? It works regardless.

Comment: @AgentK, your absolute path tip was the key. `~/Downloads/file.sh` did not work while `/home/usrname/Downloads/file.sh` did. Looks like Ubuntu doesn't like `~` for keyboard shortcuts

Comment: Wow. It's good to know this is still an issue.