# How to link a custom keyboard shortcut to a bash script in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, bash, shortcut-keys, scripts, brightness

As an Ubuntu 13.04 user I had myself as well various problems and incompatibilities with this newest version of Ubuntu. One of these is that the Brightness bar has suddenly disappeared from the 'System Settings --> Brightness & Lock' tab after I installed some packages (which I don't really remember what it was). I found out that a workaround is to use [xbacklight](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xbacklight).

As an exercise for myself, I wrote a short script in order to easily increase and decrease the brightness using xbacklight from terminal. The script is executable (has permission to execute), is an a directory that is included in $PATH in my .bashrc file and is linked to an alias ('blup' to increase and 'bldn' to decrease screen brightness). So, my two aliases (blup/bldn) work perfectly fine from a terminal line. Next, I wanted to link these to some keyboard shortcuts (for instance F2/F3). I did so in 
'System Settings --> Keyboard --> Shortcuts --> Custom Shortcuts', but it did not work.

[image]

**Why?**

Furthermore, is there a way to 'discover' where and how other (non-custom) keyboard-shortcut commands are executed? For instance, the volume-up shortcut what terminal line does it execute, what alias is connected to (if any) and what directory are they put at (/usr/bin, something else...)?

As a newbie in script-writing I would appreciate any kind of help!

Thanks

P.S.1 Of course, simply one can paste the command 'xbacklight -inc/-dec 10' to the custom keyboard shortcuts and it will work fine. I just want to seize the opportunity and get to know a bit more about script writing and executing.

P.S.2 My problem is not the same as this one: [How do I launch a bash script using a keyboard shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137117/how-do-i-launch-a-bash-script-using-a-keyboard-shortcut), ie, I use no '~/' for '/home/user/'.

Comment: This might help you http://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard/254425#254425

Comment: If you changed PATH in `.bashrc`, that change will only be available in interactive bash sessions; it will not be visible to the process doing the keyboard shortcuts. Change the PATH in `~/.profile` instead, then log out and back in.

Comment: I have tried to add the path where my scripts sit to the .profile, as you suggested, using either:
PATH=$PATH:/home/myusername/scripts or
export PATH=$PATH:/home/myusername/scripts
but none of them worked (after logging in and out). However, if I add the full path of the script to the keyboard-shortcut (sh /home/username/script/nameofscript.sh) it does work. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, aliases are not expanded in non-interactive shells. Read the `ALIASES` section from `man bash` in this sense. So, you can't use an alias in 'Command' field when you add/edit a custom shortcut.

Second, as [geirha](https://askubuntu.com/users/9016/geirha) said in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/326282/how-to-link-a-custom-keyboard-shortcut-to-a-bash-script-in-ubuntu-13-04#comment415239_326282), if you changed `PATH` in `.bashrc` file, that change will not be available in non-interactive shells. So, you need to change the `PATH` in `~/.profile` file instead.

Third, if you still want to use only `bldn` in 'Command' field when you add/edit a custom shortcut, you can rename your script with this name and add the script path to the `PATH` in `~/.profile` file, as I said above.